# git: How to get "ours, theirs, original" for merge conflicts?

Tags: git, merge-conflict-resolution, diff3

Git merge conflicts are shown like this usually:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD:file.txt
Code changed by A
=======
Code changed by B
>>>>>>> 77976da35a11db4580b80ae27e8d65caf5208086:file.txt
```

However, I know it is possible (with some `git config` option) to also show the original code and not only the changes. Something like:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD:file.txt
Code changed by A
=======
Original code
=======
Code changed by B
>>>>>>> 77976da35a11db4580b80ae27e8d65caf5208086:file.txt
```

However, I can't find the option anymore. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Never mind, I just found the  solution:

```
git config --global merge.conflictstyle diff3
```

It actually looks like this:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD:file.txt
Code changed by A
||||||| merged common ancestors
Original code
=======
Code changed by B
>>>>>>> 77976da35a11db4580b80ae27e8d65caf5208086:file.txt
```

Answer (score 4):

```
git checkout --conflict=diff3 -- file.txt
```

works for a single invocation.